# How to apply theme or customize Nebular icons?

Tags: angular, icons, nebular, ngx-admin

I working on the Nebular theme. I have to customize the icons like icon-font-size. I found the documentation [here](https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/components/icon/theme#nbiconcomponent).

```
<nb-icon icon="file-text-outline"></nb-icon>
```

My question is, How to change default values that are available [here](https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/components/icon/theme#nbiconcomponent).

I have tried

```
<nb-icon [options]={icon-font-size:'1.5rem'} icon="file-text-outline"></nb-icon>
```

But it is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that the actual syntax for changing the correct parameters is:

`<nb-icon [config]="{icon: 'file-text-outline', options: {'icon-font-size': '1.5rem'}}"></nb-icon>`

However, the display of the icons is still being controlled through the SCSS (`\@nebular\theme\styles\core\theming\_install.scss`). Therefor my suggestion would be to remove the bindings and change whatever you need through your components' SCSS. Here are the corresponding selectors for each `option`:

```
nb-icon {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  line-height: 2;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  color: #000000; //For unspecified status
  
  svg {
    vertical-align: bottom;
  }

  &.status-basic {
    color: grey;
  }

  &.status-primary {
    color: aqua;
  }

  &.status-info {
    color: bisque;
  }

  &.status-success {
    color: blueviolet;
  }

  &.status-warning {
    color: chocolate;
  }

  &.status-danger {
    color: darkgoldenrod;
  }

  &.status-control {
    color: darkseagreen;
  }
}
```

Comment: i tried this `<nb-icon [config]="{icon: 'file-text-outline', options: {'icon-font-size': '2.5rem'}}"></nb-icon>`. But not working for me.

Comment: @Udhayakumar did you read everything? I mentioned that it wouldn't work. `However, the display of the icons is still being controlled through the SCSS`. Then I added the full SCSS for each and every option.

Comment: It is working `nb-icon { font-size: 2rem; }`. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

finally, it is worked for me.

in **component.scss** file

```
nb-icon {
    font-size: 2rem;
  }
```